# iTextSharp - Using C# How to Place Text Onto PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The code below is a combination of my own work and code that I have found on this site.  It works most of the time.  However, sometimes the text is added but the PDF file is rotated 180 degrees from the text that was added.

I am using iTextSharp version 5.5.11.0

I am looking for the preferred way to accomplish the following:

- Open an existing PDF
- Specify a Font Size
- Specify a Font Color
- Specify a Starting xCoordinate and yCoordinate for the text to begin
- Specify the TEXT TO BE ADDED to the PDF
- Add this text to the original PDF file or to a NEW PDF file

It has been suggested by another user (mkl) that the method I am using in the code below is the NOT the best way to go about this task.  I should be using a PdfReader / PdfStamper strategy but am not sure how to go about this.

Can anyone provide an example of the recommended way to accomplish the items above?

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace BrazilPDFModifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            var MyProgramPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\";

            //Let's see if there is a settings file that exists where we can open it and get some defaults to use for processing...
            if(!File.Exists(MyProgramPath + "\\BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt"))
            {
                //Let's create the text file since it does not already exist...
                string[] lines = 
                    { "NAME OF THE FILE TO ADD TEXT TO                            :  InputPDF.pdf",
                      "NAME OF THE FILE THAT TEXT WAS ADDED TO                    :  OutputPDF.pdf",
                      "X-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :  6",
                      "Y-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :  6",
                      "COLOR OF THE TEXT TO ADD - RED, BLACK, GREEN, WHITE, BLUE  :  Red",
                      "FONTSIZE OF THE TEXT TO ADD - 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20    :  18",
                      "INCLUDE PAGINATION WITH THE TEXT TO ADD - YES, NO          :  Yes",
                    };
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(MyProgramPath + "BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt", lines);
            }

            //Let's open the BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt file and get some settings from it to use in our program...
            // Read the file and process it line by line.  
            int found;
            string hold;
            string StringToSearchFor;
            string InputFileName = "InputPDF.pdf";
            string OutputFileName = "OutputPDF.pdf";
            string MyXCoordinate = "6";
            string MyYCoordinate = "6";
            string MyColor = "RED";
            string MyFontSize = "18";
            string IncludePagination = "";

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(MyProgramPath + "BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt");
            while ((hold = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                hold = hold.ToUpper();
                
                StringToSearchFor = "NAME OF THE FILE TO ADD TEXT TO                            :";
                if (hold.Contains (StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        InputFileName = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }
                
                StringToSearchFor = "NAME OF THE FILE THAT TEXT WAS ADDED TO                    :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        OutputFileName = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }
                
                StringToSearchFor = "X-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyXCoordinate = (hold.Substring(found).Trim());
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "Y-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyYCoordinate = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "COLOR OF THE TEXT TO ADD - RED, BLACK, GREEN, WHITE, BLUE  :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyColor = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }
                
                StringToSearchFor = "FONTSIZE OF THE TEXT TO ADD - 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20    :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyFontSize = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "INCLUDE PAGINATION WITH THE TEXT TO ADD - YES, NO          :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        IncludePagination = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            file.Close();

            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must provide the text to add, xcoord, and ycoord in order to use this software!");
                Console.WriteLine("\nLike:  BrazilPDFModifier.exe " + "\"This is the text to add" + "\" 10 10");
                Console.WriteLine("\nThis example shows\nThe program filename followed by a SPACE\nThe text to be added to the pdf surrouned by quotation marks followed by a SPACE\nThe x coord for placing the text followed by a SPACE\nThe y coord for placing the text");
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe input filename must always be:  InputPDF.pdf");
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe output filename will always be:  OutputPDF.pdf");
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            //Let's intialize some variables now...
            string textToAdd = args[0];
            int xCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(MyXCoordinate); //Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
            int yCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32 (MyYCoordinate);
            int intMyFontSize = Convert.ToInt32(MyFontSize);
            string newPath = MyProgramPath + OutputFileName;   //This is the filename this software will ALWAYS output after processing...
            string SourceFile = MyProgramPath + InputFileName;  //This is the filename this software will ALWAYS open and process...

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(SourceFile))
            {
                //ErrorMsg = SourceFile + " cannot be found!  I must skip this file!";
                return; //Let's exit the program since we cannot do any processing...
            }

            using (var reader = new PdfReader(SourceFile))
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
                    document.Open();
                    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        document.NewPage();
                        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                        var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;

                        //Let's set the color now...
                        switch (MyColor.ToUpper())
                        {
                            case "RED":
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                                break;
                            case "BLACK":
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                                break;
                            case "GREEN":
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN);
                                break;
                            case "WHITE":
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                                break;
                            case "BLUE":
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
                                break;
                            default:
                                contentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                                break;
                        }
                       
                        contentByte.BeginText();
                        contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, intMyFontSize);
                        
                        if (IncludePagination.ToUpper() != "YES")
                        {
                            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, textToAdd, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, textToAdd + " Pg:" + i + "/" + reader.NumberOfPages, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0);
                        }
                        
                        contentByte.EndText();
                        if(reader.GetPageRotation(1) == 90 || reader.GetPageRotation(1) == 270)
                        {
                            //*** I think the problem might be in this block somewhere but could be totally wrong.
                            contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    document.Close();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of rotated PDF and text is normal:
[Image of PDF file with text at bottom but PDF data it rotated 180 deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKIEL.jpg)

Comment: To answer your question about the version: you can see that in the properties of the DLL. But indeed, most likely version 5.x.x. Current version is 7.1.11 (7.1.12 will be released later this month) and it's no longer called *iTextSharp* but *iText 7 for .NET*.

Comment: I see that others have voted to close your question. I don't agree, and I have the power to reopen your question, but that would be useless because it would be closed again in a matter of hours. However there is still plenty of room for improvement of your question. You write too much. I suggest that you delete all the background information (we don't need to know that you are not a developer). Just stick to the technicalities and delete everything else.

Comment: Put some structure in your question. Use bullet points. Describe expected and actual behavior. Make your code example shorter, the current code is 10 times too long. Make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Ok.  I attempted to remove a lot of the background information and ask a more direct question.  I left the entire code listing in case anyone wanted to test it or use it if desired.  It works for most PDF files as is.  I added a comment in the code where I think the problem might be.

Comment: For your task *to create a tool that can place additional text onto existing PDF files* you already started with a not so appropriate approach: You should have based your routine on a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` couple instead of a `PdfReader` / `PdfWriter` one. And then there are issues in your implementation of that not so appropriate approach. Would you like help with your approach or with the in general more appropriate other one?

Comment: I would love to have a full working code of the appropriate approach.  I am not a C# programmer but am just trying to find a solution that will work for me.  I have been able to write some simple code to do some simple things but I am at a total loss about how this itextsharp.dll works and cannot get it figured out.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I think I have it sorted out but would appreciate some expert help to look it over to see if I have missed anything or if there are better ways to accomplish the tasks listed in my original question.  Would be nice if MKL or Amedee Van Gasse could provide some feedback as they seem very knowledgeable and provided me some guidance on my very first posting here at stackoverflow.

Here is my complete code listing in case this is helpful to anyone that happens to need a tool to add text to PDF files.  Seems like this code should be readily available for such a simple and common task as this seems to be.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BrazilPDFModifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            var MyProgramPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\";

            //Let's see if there is a settings file that exists where we can open it and get some defaults to use for processing...
            if (!File.Exists(MyProgramPath + "\\BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt"))
            {
                //Let's create the text file since it does not already exist...
                string[] lines =
                    { "NAME OF THE FILE TO ADD TEXT TO                            :  InputPDF.pdf",
                      "NAME OF THE FILE THAT TEXT WAS ADDED TO                    :  OutputPDF.pdf",
                      "X-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :  5",
                      "Y-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :  5",
                      "COLOR OF THE TEXT TO ADD - RED, BLACK, GREEN, WHITE, BLUE  :  Red",
                      "FONTSIZE OF THE TEXT TO ADD - 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20    :  12",
                      "INCLUDE PAGINATION WITH THE TEXT TO ADD - YES, NO          :  Yes",
                    };
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(MyProgramPath + "BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt", lines);
            }

            //Let's open the BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt file and get some settings from it to use in our program...
            // Read the file and process it line by line.  
            int found;
            string hold;
            string StringToSearchFor;
            string InputFileName = "InputPDF.pdf";
            string OutputFileName = "OutputPDF.pdf";
            string MyXCoordinate = "6";
            string MyYCoordinate = "6";
            string MyColor = "RED";
            string MyFontSize = "12";
            string IncludePagination = "Yes";

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(MyProgramPath + "BrazilPdfModifierSettings.txt");
            while ((hold = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                hold = hold.ToUpper();

                StringToSearchFor = "NAME OF THE FILE TO ADD TEXT TO                            :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        InputFileName = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "NAME OF THE FILE THAT TEXT WAS ADDED TO                    :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        OutputFileName = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "X-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyXCoordinate = (hold.Substring(found).Trim());
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "Y-COORDINATE FOR PLACING THE TEXT ONTO THE PDF             :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyYCoordinate = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "COLOR OF THE TEXT TO ADD - RED, BLACK, GREEN, WHITE, BLUE  :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyColor = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "FONTSIZE OF THE TEXT TO ADD - 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20    :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        MyFontSize = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }

                StringToSearchFor = "INCLUDE PAGINATION WITH THE TEXT TO ADD - YES, NO          :";
                if (hold.Contains(StringToSearchFor))
                {
                    found = hold.ToUpper().IndexOf(StringToSearchFor) + StringToSearchFor.Length;
                    if (found > 0)
                    {
                        IncludePagination = hold.Substring(found).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
            file.Close();
            
            //Let's intialize some variables now...
            string TextToAdd = args[0];
            int xCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(MyXCoordinate);
            int yCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(MyYCoordinate);
            int intMyFontSize = Convert.ToInt32(MyFontSize);
            
            if (args.Length < 1 && args.Length != 6)    //We must pass in the TextToAdd at a minimum
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must pass parameters to use this software!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Like:  BrazilPDFModifier.exe " + "\"This is the text to add" + "\" 10 10 12 Red Yes extra");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("This example shows...");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("The program filename followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("The text to be added to the pdf surrouned by quotation marks followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("The x coordinate for placing the text followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("The y coordinate for placing the text followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("The Font Size you want to use followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("The Font Color you want to use followed by a SPACE");
                Console.WriteLine("Include pagination Yes or No");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Unless you change it in the settings file, I will use InputPDF.pdf as the file to process");
                Console.WriteLine("Unless you change it in the settings file, I will use OutputPDF.pdf as the file that will contain the added text.");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
            else if (args.Length > 1)   //If we have more than one parameter passed in we must pass in all required parameters
            {
                TextToAdd = args[0];
                xCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
                yCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
                intMyFontSize = Convert.ToInt32(args[3]);
                MyColor = args[4];
                IncludePagination = args[5];
            }

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(MyProgramPath + InputFileName))
            {
                //ErrorMsg = SourceFile + " cannot be found!  I must skip this file!";
                return; //Let's exit the program since we cannot do any processing...
            }
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            using (var newPDF = new FileStream(MyProgramPath + OutputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MyProgramPath + InputFileName);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, newPDF);
                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    PdfContentByte pdfContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(page);
                    pdfContent.BeginText();
                    pdfContent.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, intMyFontSize);

                    //Let's set the color now...
                    switch (MyColor.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "RED":
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                            break;
                        case "BLACK":
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                            break;
                        case "GREEN":
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case "WHITE":
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                            break;
                        case "BLUE":
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
                            break;
                        default:
                            pdfContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (IncludePagination.ToUpper() != "YES")
                    {
                        pdfContent.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, TextToAdd, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pdfContent.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, TextToAdd + " Pg:" + page + "/" + reader.NumberOfPages, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0);
                    }
                    pdfContent.EndText();
                }
                pdfStamper.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Please be aware, though, that each page of a PDF may have its own coordinate system, the origin is not always in the lower left corner.

Comment: Thanks mkl.  Any chance you or anyone else can share a code snippet that I could add to my code that could address that possible condition where the origin may not always be at the bottom left?